# Two tables with a Join Size error works fine on server

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to compare two tables and only return from the first table records that do not have a match for a specific attribute in the 2nd 
attributeData table. We store lots of attributes in one table.

This is to return courses that have not had a specific email sent and record in that attributeData Table.

It works fine on the server via `phpMyAdmin` but running it results in the `MAX_JOIN_SIZE` error even with big select on.

```
SELECT studentCourse.studentCourseId
FROM studentCourse, attributeData 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (
  SELECT attributeData.entityID FROM attributeData 
  WHERE attributeData.entityID = studentCourse.studentCourseId
  )
AND (studentCourse.startDate >= '2017-12-15') 
AND attributeData.attributeID = 244
AND (studentCourse.sclLastLessonDate = '0000-00-00')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as would help with the issue we are having using the school system.

Has to be a way to make the query compare and since the returned data is not large (say 30 rows)

Comment: I dont think its a duplicate post, its similar but there has to be a way to do a query like this without hitting the limit